# Drupal::config to access Site default timezone

Tags: 8, configuration

Like the title says, I want to access the sites default timezone.

Guess

```
Drupal::config('system.date')->get('timezone')['default']
```

is the right function.
I really would love to know how to use the config-function. Is there a list with all the configs, settings or variables that can be called?

Whats the logic behind the keywords "system.date"? Is there a way to discover keywords by looking at the yml config structure? Can all values of them be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Inspect the system.date configuration**

You can navigate to the */admin/config/development/configuration/single/export* path and inspect the configuration types and values. The *default timezone* is of type *simple configuration* and *system.date* is the *cofiguration name*.

**Inspect all the configuration values**

Go to */admin/config/development/configuration/full/export*, here you can export all the active configuration, you can download and extract the bundle and then inspect the individual files. If you have the *drush* command line tool, you could use the command `drush config:export`.

**Official Documentation**

You should read the official documentation to better understand the logic behind the *Configuration API*. These are some links:

[Simple Configuration API | Drupal 8 guide on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/simple-configuration-api)

[Configuration API | Drupal 8 guide on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api)

[Configuration API overview | Drupal 8 guide on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/configuration-api-overview)